# TabView Item does not show View item at first on ipad

Tags: ios, swift, ipad, swiftui, tabview

I have a `tabView` for categorizing pages and it works well on iPhone, but it does not show on iPad the first time when I run the app and the user must press view name on the top left page to see the view (like the following image)
[image].

and this is the code for the above image:

```
struct MainView: View {
    
    init() {
        
    }
    let items = Bundle.main.decode(MainModel.self, from: "items.json")
    var body: some View {
        TabView {
            partOneView(items: items.partOne)
                .tabItem { Label("Part One", systemImage: "folder.circle.fill")}
            PartTwoView(items: items.partTwo)
                .tabItem { Label("Part Two", systemImage: "square.grid.3x1.folder.fill.badge.plus")}
            partThreeView(items: items.partThree)
                .tabItem{ Label("Part 3", systemImage:"tray.circle.fill")}
        }
        
    }
}
```

But I need something like the following image and I want to do not allow it to hide the view

[image]

Comment: This isn’t and issue of the TabView it is a known behavior of the List that is likely housed in the partOneView. There are several solutions in SO some suggest to stick to a stack navigation view. Some say to add a welcome view to the navigation view. If you put the iPad on landscape the list will be out. You can have a default value for the selection too. You just have to find a workaround for your use case.

Comment: You set `.navigationViewStyle(StackNavigationViewStyle())` ON the navigation view itself, not inside it like you would a title.

Comment: Thanks @Yrb It worked, but with another view :)